# The meaning of "usage"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, exam-questions

Fill in the blank

> The way people actually speak and write a language .......
> a) linguist
> b) statement
> c) subject
> d) usage

I have been eliminate other choices that can be the answer. So it should be "usage". But why it is true? I think usage means the way we use something.

Comment: Alternatives include ***vernacular, everyday language, spoken language, colloquial speech, conversational language, common parlance,...*** But I don't understand the point of the question. The word "usage" does indeed mean *the way we use something*, but are you just asking us to confirm that for you? Note that your ***noun phrase*** as written *(**the way people actually speak and write a language**)* doesn't require (or indeed allow) an additional noun (such as "usage") to follow.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica Thank you. Yes I doubted about this meaning because in OALD also I haven't find this meaning.

Comment: The [definition of usage in The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Usage) that applies would be *The way in which words or phrases are actually used, spoken, or written in a speech community: Dictionaries are but the depositories of words already legitimated by usage" (Thomas Jefferson).*